# Ayuda con Helpers en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy empezando con CodeIgniter.
pero me encontré con un bache dentro de mi aplicacion web, es simplemente un hola mundo usando helpers propios. paso código

controller

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class CodigoFacilito extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('mihelper');
    }
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('codigoFacilito/bienvenido');
    }
    function holaMundo(){
        $this->load->view('codigoFacilito/headers');
        $this->load->view('codigoFacilito/bienvenido');
    }
}
?>
```

View

```
<body>
    <h1>Llamado desde el controlador CF</h1>
    <?= getNombre()?>
</body>
</html>
```

Helper

```
<?
    function getNombre(){
        return "<h1>Daniel</h1>";
    }
?>
```

la verdad el tutorial es muy viejo y no se si aun asi se usa la codificacion.
 el error que me sale es este

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to undefined function getNombre()
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\views\codigoFacilito\bienvenido.php
>   Line Number: 3
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\CodigoFacilito.php
>   Line: 15
>   Function: view
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.
saludos y gracias

Comment: el nombre del archivo que contiene el helper debería ser `mihelper_helper.php` y estar en la carpeta helpers

Comment: asi es como lo tengo, junto con su respectiva carpeta.
pero ya vi cual es mi error, y es que en el helper la funcion debe ir con 
<?php
function{....}
?>

Comment: prueba poner `<?php $this->load->helper('mihelper'); ?>` en la vista también (justo antes del body) , teóricamente no sería necesario pero creo que varía entre versiones de CI

Comment: gracias alo Malvarez, era eso... gracias por tu comentario que me ayudo mucho

Comment: vale, que versión de CI es? está en `const CI_VERSION ` dentro de `system/core/Codeigniter.php`

Comment: la version de CI es 3.1.9

Comment: gracias! lo voy a probar en esa versión, por cierto si es un helper que usas en todo el proyecto lo podes poner en el array de  `app/config/autoload.php`